# Change directory/ path in beginning of syntax will change all the following identical directories

Tags: r, replace, path, directory, paste

I have have a working directory:

```
setwd("C:/Patient migration")
```

then I have other directories where I save my workspace data and where I get the source data from.

```
C:/Patient migration/source data
C:/Patient migration/workspace
```

As this directories appear many times in the syntax (as part of a complete path name) and as other persons should be able to work with my syntax as well.
Such a directory later on in the syntax would look like this:

```
save (SCICases2010,file="C:/Patient migration/Workspace/SCICases2010.RData")

Data22 <- read.table(file = "C:/Patient migration/source data/DATA_BFS_MS_GEO_NiNo_2010_2.dat", sep = "|", header = TRUE)
```

Is it possible to change a directory once, for example in the beginning, so that all the same directories in the syntax further down will be changed as well?

My goal is that i can name the 2 or 3 directories in the beginning of my syntax. Other users can change those and consequently all the other directories somewhere in the syntax change as well.

Do you understand what I want to do? Are there probably smarter ways to do that?
I don't really want all this data in the working directory.

Hopefully somebody can help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. I use relative paths which start with the subfolder where the data i need comes from or where the output is going to. This subfolder is lying in the working directory.

Like that I just need to change the working directory. Everything else can stay the same.

```
save (SCICases2010,file="C:/Patient migration/Workspace/SCICases2010.RData")
```

becomes

```
Patient migration/Workspace/SCICases2010.RData")
```

and

```
Data22 <- read.table(file = "C:/Patient migration/source data/DATA_BFS_MS_GEO_NiNo_2010_2.dat", sep = "|", header = TRUE)
```

becomes

```
source data/DATA_BFS_MS_GEO_NiNo_2010_2.dat", sep = "|", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can firstly label your file with names in the beginning of your syntax like this

```
source.file <- "C:/Patient migration/source data"
work.file <- "C:/Patient migration/workspace"
```

Then you can just use the names of those paths rather than type it every time.
Other user of your syntax can set the file path in the beginning and need not change the following code any more.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but it didn't work for me. I didn't provide you with the complete information in the initial post. I updated that now. This directory will be just a part of a complete path.

Comment: Maybe you can change your following directories like this:      paste(source.file, "/SCICases2010.RData", sep = "")    source.file is what you defined in the beginning; "/SCICases2010.RData" is the object name you use latter.